# What variant of Spline algorithm is used in "spline" parameter from "scale" filter?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, video-encoding, scaling

FFmpeg has two filters to scale the video: `scale` and `zscale` - `zscale` has `spline16` and `spline36` parameters (they represent Spline16 and Spline36 variants of the algorithm), `scale` has `spline` parameter.

Does anyone know what variant of Spline algorithm is that `spline` from `scale`?

Comment: Which ffmpeg version are you asking about? I couldn't find 'spline' in vf_scale source code (the closest thing being a single mention in 'cubic2p_bspline').

Comment: @user1686 Spline was present in any version of FFmpeg I was using, even in the oldest one (which was 4.3). It is listed in the current [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-scaler.html) together with other `scale` options (like Bilinear, Bicubic and Lanczos).

Comment: @user1686 The function [is here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/a4388ebd37e42721e294946721d5c008ca0b3e66/libswscale/utils.c#L327-L329) as far as I can tell.

Comment: @user1686 I don't quite understand this code but I found the line with `else if (flags&SWS_LANCZOS) sizeFactor= param[0] != SWS_PARAM_DEFAULT ? ceil(2*param[0]) : 6;` that relates to the documentation that Lanczos option depends on `param0` parameter so this must be it.

Comment: @slhck Just below the code I mentioned in the previous comment I can see something like this `else if (flags&SWS_SPLINE) sizeFactor= 20;  // infinite ;)` - does that mean that `scale` filter is using some unusual option like Spline20? Unusual for me, because it's out of the possibilities I know (Spline16, Spline36, Spline64). Why is this line's comment "infinite"? These both lines also suggest that there is no option to change the default Spline algorithm in `scale` filter (as it does not check any parameters).